# Proof of limits using epsilon-delta rule

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

Prove: $\lim_{x\to 3}\frac 1x=\frac 13$;

According to the epsilon-delta rule *if*
$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ *whenever* $|x-a|<\delta$, *then* $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

Steps I Followed:
$\left|\frac1x-\frac13\right|=\frac{|3-x|}{3|x|}=\frac{|x-3|}{3|x|}<\frac{|x-3|}{3}$ *as* $x\to3$, *i.e.* $x>1$

Now, if we choose $\delta=3\epsilon$

we can write $\left|\frac1x-\frac13\right|<\frac{|x-3|}{3}<\frac{\delta}{3}=\epsilon\\$
which ends our proof.

I would like to know if the steps performed in the first line are correct, i.e. whether we can use this sort of assumption here.

Comment: Correct. It's a good practice to try different numbers.

Comment: You did the first to next to last line perfectly but you need to add to the last line an introductory clause that you are assume $|x-3| < \delta$ in the first place.  e.g.  "Whenever $|x - 3| < \delta$ and $x > $ then $|\frac 1x - 13| < \frac {|x-3|}3 < \frac{\delta} 3 < \epsilon$".  Ideally you want to do the proof directly "For epsilon let delta = ....  When |x-a| < delta then .... |f(x) - c| < epsilon" but as we have to calculate delta we usually do these proofs backwards as you did.  Which is fine but then we need to recap a statement that the argument works in the forward direction.

Comment: @juniven.  Why?  What the OP did is already much more general and correct.  Specific numbers are good to get inspiration but the OP has already figured it out completely.

Comment: Epsilon-delta is *not* a rule.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Maybe this can help.
Let $\epsilon >0$. If $|x-3|<1$, then we get
$$2<x<4$$
and so with this, we can take $\delta=\min\{6\epsilon,1\}$. Thus, if $|x-3|<\delta$, then
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3}\right|&=\frac{|x-3|}{3|x|}\\
&=\frac{|x-3|}{3x}\\
&<\frac{\delta}{6}\\
&\leq \epsilon.
\end{align}
The result follows.

Comment: But $|x-3|<1 \not \implies 1<x<4$

Answer (score 1):

Given an $\epsilon>0$, we look for $\eta>0 $ such that

$$|x-3|<\eta \implies |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3}|<\epsilon$$

as $x$ tends to $3$, we can suppose that $2<x<4$. then $ |x-3|<\color{red}{1} $ and $\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{2}$.
thus
$$|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3}|=\frac{|x-3|}{3x}<\frac{1}{6}|x-3|$$

Now, we see that we can take $\eta=\min(\color{red}{1},6\epsilon)$.

Instead of the condition $2<x<4$, one could take $1<x<5$. In this case he will have $|x-3|<\color{red}{2}$ and

$\frac{1}{3x}<\frac{1}{3}$.
So he will take $\eta=\min(\color{red}{2},3\epsilon).$

Answer (score 1):

$$
|x-3|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3}\right|\le \max\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3+\delta},\frac{1}{3-\delta}-\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{\delta}{3-\delta} \to 0.
$$